# In JavaScript how to force a function finish execution before return some data

Tags: javascript

I want to use PhoneGap to read a file then return me the data of that file, but when i execute the code, it return before read the file. The code below shows how to read file:

```
function getData() {
    var fileData = null;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
      function gotFS(fileSystem) {
         fileSystem.root.getFile("data.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
         function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
         }
         function gotFile(file){
            readAsText(file);
         }

        function readAsText(file) {
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            fileData = evt.target.result;
                alert(fileData) 
               // this alert is executed after returning the data, so it return the data, but the second alert return null when this is method called.
           };
           reader.readAsText(file);
        }
    }
    return fileData;
}
```

Now when i call that function, it will return null

```
var data = getData();
alert(data); // return null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an asynchronous method so you'll have to use a callback.

Change `getData` so it accepts a callback:

```
function getData(callback) { ....
```

Then where you are alerting, do this instead:

```
if (callback) callback(fileData);
```

Now you can call your function like so:

```
var _data;

getData(function(data) { 
 // do stuff with data ...
 _data = data;
 alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, looks much better now.  I wrote the original answer on my mobile phone so it was a bit quick'n'dirty :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have synchonously the result of an asynchonous query.

check the first response of that for more details : [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)